# What is correct Solr Fuzzy search syntax?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have been trying to do fuzzy search in Solr from java web service, but adding ~ to the search query isn't working.

My non-fuzzy query looks like:

```
((param_name : "gold") // Works return items with "gold" in it
```

To make it fuzzy I tried adding ~ multiple ways but nothing seems to work

```
((param_name : "glod~") // Adding inside quotes

((param_name : "glod"~) // Adding outside quotes

((param_name : "glod"\~)) // Escaping
```

Only thing which actually works is not adding quotes at all, but I have to add quotes so that special characters etc will work.

```
((param_name : glod~)) // works, returns matching results
```

Have anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you need to escape special characters manually.

To escape these character use the \ before the character.

**In Solr quotes are using for phrases.**

If you want to combine fuzzy phrase search you need to do:

```
((param_name : glod~) AND param_name : glod~))
```

`((param_name : glod~))` is a right way of doing it.

Doing this `"gold year"~10` will run  a proximity search.
For example to search for a "**gold**" and "**year**" within 10 words of each other in a document use the search